# Bridge */arduino/analog/2 returns a blank page

Tags: arduino-yun, analogread, h-bridge

Had some start up difficulties. But updated the YUN and IDE to the latest version.

Using  `* "/arduino/digital/13/1"` works as supposed (turns on the LED) - it's just a bit slow. But I can't see why the analogs shouldn't work. I tried to connect it to 5V or GND, so it wasn't floating. But it still returns no reading.

Don't know if this is the cause. But when I connect to my router I can't the the YUN in the list of DHCP Clients...